Question about Euler angles and rotation about relative and fixed frames?
I'm studying linear algebra, and one of the topics is rotation through euler angles. Depending on the sequence, we obviously get different results. One thing that I'm confused about however, is that for certain orders (X-Y-Z) the rotation is about a fixed coordinate frame whereas for others (Z-Y-X) the rotation is about a relative coordinate frame? From this book, Introduction to Robotics by John Craig, the following is mentioned:



I am confused as to what changes between these orders that causes the rotation frame to be fixed or relative. Another example is Y-Z-Y where the rotation frame is relative (like Z-Y-X). Furthermore, I know that euler angles are divided into two types: Proper and Tait-Bryan. Does this affect anything?

Observe that $R_{X,Y,Z}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma) =R_Z(\alpha)R_Y(\beta)R_X(\gamma)= R_{Z',Y',X'}(\alpha,\beta,\gamma)$.
Explanation: In the Euler angle notation, once I have rotated about the $Z=Z'$ axis, I now want to rotate about the $Y'$ axis. But the $Y'$ axis is $\hat{Y}'=R_{Z}(\alpha)\hat{Y}$. So to rotate an angle $\beta$ about $\hat{Y}'$ I can rotate about $\hat{Y}$ after first applying $R_Z^{-1}(\alpha)$.
That is, $R_{Y'}(\beta) = R_Z(\alpha)R_Y(\beta)R_{Z}^{-1}(\beta)$.
Similarly, $R_{X'}(\gamma) = (R_YR_Z) R_X(\gamma) (R_YR_Z)^{-1}$.
So $R_{X'}R_{Y'}R_{Z'} = R_YR_ZR_XR_Z^{-1}R_Y^{-1}R_ZR_YR_Z^{-1}R_Z = R_{Z,Y,X}$. It's not that the order you rotate in determines whether you use a fixed frame or a moving frame. I can do other orders too and use both notations (e.g. $R_{Y,Z,Y} = R_{Y',Z',Y'}$) but the point is that the ordering for moving frame rotations is the reverse of that for the fixed frame notation.
